# "My room bulb blew out/fused" "How does candle blow out"

Tags: transitivity

I think "My room bulb blew out/fused" is wrong. Shouldn't it be: "My room bulb has been blown/fused"? A bulb cannot blow or fuse itself. Doesn't it require an object to blow/fuse it?

Similarly, I think "My room bulb blows out/fuses" is wrong. Shouldn't it be "My room bulb is blown out/fused"(in passive voice)?

Similarly, I think "why does the candle blow out" is wrong. Shouldn't it be "Why is the candle blown out"(in passive voice)?

Comment: Have you verified your suspicions with a dictionary?

Comment: I am still verifying it. When i posted the question, I had different opinion which I elborated in question earlier but now i think eitherway could be correct but i am not pretty sure.

Comment: "A bulb cannot blow or fuse itself" - but they can! With the old filament type bulbs, a portion of the filament eventually (and inevitably) grows weak with age, due to metal fatigue and evaporation, and becomes detached or breaks. This may just cause the bulb to simply not work, but often it causes a short circuit which blows a fuse or trips a circuit breaker. An outside agent is not required. Modern LED or fluorescent bulbs can still fail internally but less often.

Comment: You don't have to post comments thanking the answerers. If you find an answer helpful to you, please upvote and/or accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries can often help.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/blow?locale=en)'s definition 3.3 of **blow**,

"burn out or be caused to burn out through overloading"

shows that a bulb CAN blow, and it can also be blown.

Their first definition of **[blow out](https://www.lexico.com/definition/blow_out)** is

"Be extinguished by an air current"

and the first example given is "the candles blew out."

You may have come across, "The car stopped," "A bell rang," "The door opened." Can a car stop or a bell ring or a door open? Luckily they can. A piece of writing that overuses the passive voice can quickly become tedious.

Answer (score 0):

"My room bulb" is not idiomatic English. You can use "the bulb in my room."

This is idiomatic English

> The bulb in my room blew out.

to say that the bulb has failed.

For the candle, these are idiomatic English:

> My candle was blown out.
> My candle blew out.